# Using draw.io is it possible to navigate through the tab list using the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, xml, tabs

I am using draw.io to view some block diagrams. I have dozens of tabs in each of my XML files. Is it possible to navigate through the tab list using the keyboard vs clicking on each tab using the mouse/trackpad? I couldn't figure out how to do it :)

-reacher33

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a Mac I have found the keyboard shortcuts to be:

- <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>< Left arrow</kbd> for moving left through the tabs
- and (unsurprisingly) <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>> Right arrow</kbd> for moving right

If I get a chance to try this on Windows some time I will try to remember to add the key combo here, but try some of the combinations with the arrow keys to see what happens.

Comment: That works on my updated Mac, thanks. Not working on my other machine. Think I'll still with the Mac for now.

Answer (score 0):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> to move to the previous page.

Or

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> to move to the next page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Reddy. The command you listed allows for selecting the first and last tabs. Adding left and right arrow keys instead of PgUp and PgDn appear to move the highlighted tab in either direction. I was looking for a way to select and open a tab to show the diagram without having to use the mouse. Looking back at my OP, I didn't make that point clear. Thanks for the feedback.